# Replace max value in each row of numpy array w/out for loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like so, reshaped it, and need to replace the max value in each row (so axis=1?) with 0. I can't use for loops.

```
x = np.random.uniform(1.0, 21.0, 20)
print("Original array: ", x)

xMatrix = x.reshape(4, 5)
print(xMatrix)

maxNum = np.amax(xMatrix, axis=1)
```

So, maxNum only gives me the max value in each row, obviously. But how would I go about actually replacing those values without simply looping through the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try np.where combined with np.isin :

```
np.where(np.isin(xMatrix,maxNum), 0, xMatrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a way to do this in a single pass, unlike other answers here that first find the max and then search for it.

This solution finds the INDEX of the max value in each row, then assigns 0 to that index.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(1.0, 21.0, 20)
print("Original array: ", x)

xMatrix = x.reshape(4, 5)
print(xMatrix)
```

gives

> ```
> xMatrix
> Out[28]: 
> array([[10.10437809,  6.4552141 , 15.1040498 ,  1.94380305, 15.27380855],
>        [12.08934681, 19.20744506, 14.12271304,  8.45470779,  6.2887767 ],
>        [ 7.74326665, 14.63460522, 12.07651464, 15.80510958,  2.24595519],
>        [16.12620326, 16.29083185,  7.96133555, 10.61357712, 14.6664017 ]])
> ```

then

```
max_ind = np.argmax(xMatrix, axis=1)
row_ind = np.arange(xMatrix.shape[0])
multi_ind = np.array([row_ind, max_ind])
linear_ind = np.ravel_multi_index(multi_ind, xMatrix.shape)
xMatrix.reshape((-1))[linear_ind] = 0
```

> ```
> xMatrix
> Out[37]: 
> array([[10.10437809,  6.4552141 , 15.1040498 ,  1.94380305,  0.        ],
>        [12.08934681,  0.        , 14.12271304,  8.45470779,  6.2887767 ],
>        [ 7.74326665, 14.63460522, 12.07651464,  0.        ,  2.24595519],
>        [16.12620326,  0.        ,  7.96133555, 10.61357712, 14.6664017 ]])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and lamda function like this

```
list(map(lambda x : max(x), xMatrix))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it what you are looking for
Use simple comparison operators and its done

```
xMatrix[xMatrix == max_num[:, None]] = 0
```